# Working with a regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I've a string with alpha numeric terms like below. I want to extract alphabets into an array. I've written following code.

```
String pro = "1a1a2aa3aaa4aaaa15aaaaa6aaaaaa";
String[] p = pro.split("^([0-9].*)$");

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([0-9].*)([A-z].*)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(pro.toString());
while (matcher.find())
{
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
for(String s: p)
{
    System.out.println(s);
}
System.out.println("End");
```

Output:

```
1a1a2aa3aaa4aaaa15aaaaa6aaaaaa
ENd
```

I even tried to use split based on regular expression, but even that is not true. I think my regular expression is wrong. I'm expecting output with all the alphabets in array.

```
array[] = {'a', 'a', 'aa', 'aaa', 'aaaa', 'aaaaa', 'aaaaaa'}
```

Comment: I am not sure what you want to do. By me an alphabet is like `a,b,c,d,e,...`. If you want to work with unicode characters, try to use unicode regex for that.

Comment: I guess you were looking for the term: `alphabetic character`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the following which `split`(s) on anything except alphabetic characters.

```
String s = "1a1a2aa3aaa4aaaa15aaaaa6aaaaaa";
String[] parts = s.split("[^a-zA-Z]+")

for (String m: parts) {
    System.out.println(m);
}
```

Using the `Matcher` method, you could do the  following.

```
String s  = "1a1a2aa3aaa4aaaa15aaaaa6aaaaaa";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

List<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();

while (m.find()) {
  matches.add(m.group());
}

System.out.println(matches); // => [a, a, aa, aaa, aaaa, aaaaa, aaaaaa]
```

Comment: This will also match things like @'$ and other special characters not necessarily alphabet letters. It is matching is based on numbers

Answer (score 0):

If you want only alphabet characters wouldn't make more sense to use this expression instead:  `/([a-zA-Z]+)/g`

using `^` and `$` is not something you may want in your expression because what you want instead is to match all possible matches `/g`

Here is an online demo:

http://regex101.com/r/fI1eB8